# finding out Bluetooth State without a Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, bluetooth, state

I'd like to know if there is any way I can simply check whether a Bluetooth device is currently connected - I don't want to use a broadcast receiver - just check the state. I can't seem find out how this is done.

I currently have a listener that does listen to state changes with Bluetooth, and changes an internal variable accordingly - but, even though it sounds weird just saying it, it actually seems to miss the Bluetooth device disconnect broadcast *sometimes*. what I would like to do is run an additional check to see if the device really is still connected, or if the broadcast was missed...

so, how do I do this?

Thanks for reading/helping!

Answer (score 0):

I use this to check the state of Bluetooth. I don't know how to check if is currently connected to another device but I think this can be a start point.

```
    private void CheckBlueToothState() {
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        //stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth NOT support");
    } else {
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                //stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is currently in device discovery process.");
            } else {
                //stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is Enabled.");
            }
        } else {
            //stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is NOT Enabled!");
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
}
```